# Combine requests and yield results as soon as possible

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Short version: How do I implement the `GetAndFetchLatest` method like Akavache in my own code ( https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/501b397d8c071366c3b6783aae3e98695b3d7442/src/Akavache/Portable/JsonSerializationMixin.cs#L202 ) - as in without adding Akavache?

Long version:
I have a method that returns a list of T from disk and I have a method that returns same type `List<T>` from HTTP service.
Both wrapped asynchronous as `Task<List<T>>`

In my view model I would only like to call 1 method that returns an `Observable<List<T>>`.

So that in my ViewModel I use the `.Subscribe()` method to update the UI.
In essence I need to be notified twice that data is available and the code in the subscribe will also be done twice.

This feature is available in Akavache in the form of the `GetAndFetchLatest` method... but I'm nowhere near as fluent in RX to understand how I can implement this myself with my 2 data method calls.

Note: so I don't want to wait for both tasks! I want to trigger both at the same time and as soon as they return with data notify the `Observable`.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `Task<List<T>> GetFromWeb()` and `Task<List<T>> GetFromDisk()`, the simple answer is this:

```
var merged = Observable.Merge(
    GetFromWeb().ToObservable(),
    GetFromDisk().ToObservable()
);

//Same thing using extension syntax
var simply = GetFromWeb().ToObservable()
    .Merge(GetFromDisk().ToObservable());
```

However, that doesn't handle the unlikely but possible scenario that `GetFromWeb` finishes before `GetFromDisk` in which case I'm assuming you want to ignore the results of `GetFromDisk`. To handle that, you're going to require some gymnastics:

```
public IObservable<T> Prioritize<T>(params IObservable<T>[] orderedByDescendingPriority)
{
    return orderedByDescendingPriority
        .Select((o, i) => o.Select(item => Tuple.Create(orderedByDescendingPriority.Length - i, item)))
        .Merge()
        .Select(t => new Func<Tuple<int, T, bool>, Tuple<int, T, bool>>(t2 => Tuple.Create(Math.Max(t2.Item1, t.Item1), t.Item2, t.Item1 >= t2.Item1)))
        .Scan(Tuple.Create(0, default(T), false), (t, f) => f(t))
        .Where(t => t.Item3)
        .Select(t => t.Item2);
}

var merged = Prioritize(
    GetFromWeb().ToObservable(),
    GetFromDisk().ToObservable()
);
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you always want `GetFromDisk` to show up always before `GetFromWeb` then it's a simple `Concat` operation. This works because .NET tasks automatically start as soon as you reference their functions:

```
    var t1 = GetFromDisk();
    var t2 = GetFromWeb();

    var merged = Observable.Concat(
        t1.ToObservable(),
        t2.ToObservable()
    );
```

Comment: Is there maybe a way to not prioritise but to defer the fromWeb result after the fromDisk result is pushed? So not wait with start of the fromWeb but do wait with adding the results to the observable after the ones of the fromDisk are pushed?

Comment: So begin requests at same time, and no matter how long `FromDisk` takes, it will always come out first, followed by `FromWeb` as soon as available?

Comment: Basically start requests at same time but maintain FIFO queue ordering on the results?

Comment: Yes that is it!!